# Get Li clicked index number

Tags: javascript, events, html-lists

How to get clicked li index number, without any dataset attribute addition to li elements

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach(function(li) {
    li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(this); // how to get clicked li index number, without any dataset additon to li elements
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>House</li>
    <li>Building</li>
    <li>Factory</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the index of the clicked `li` element, you can use the below given code snippet.

```
 var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach(function(li,i) { //i is the index of the list item
    li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(this,i); // how to get clicked li index number, without any dataset additon to li elements
    });
});
```